# Integer solutions of the equation $a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n = 2001 $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am doing number theory and I came across that question $a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n = 2001 $. Find the integer solutions and show that they are the only solution.
 I really tried hard but i am nowhere near solution.

Comment: $a=2002$ and $n=0$.

Comment: How did u get 13 and 2

Comment: Notice that $a^{n+1} - (a+1)^n - 2001$ is a monic polynomial in $a$ with integer coefficients and constant term $-2002$. Hence by the rational root theorem any integer $a$ solving the above must divide $2002$. This leaves finitely many possibilities for $a$ which should allow you to easily finish the problem.

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3028616#p3028616).

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming $a,n$ are positive integers.

First of all, $a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n \equiv -1 \equiv 2001 \;\; \text{mod} \; a ,$ so $a$ divides $2002=2 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13. $ Because $3|2001$ then $a^{n+1} \equiv (a+1)^n \;\; \text{mod} \; 3.$ You can easily eliminate $a \equiv 0,-1 \;\; \text{mod} \; 3,$ therefore, $a \equiv 1 \;\; \text{mod} \; 3 \;(\star)$ and $n$ has to be **even**.

*Case 1.* If $a$ is even, then $ a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n \equiv -1 \;\; \text{mod} \; 4$ but $2001 \equiv 1 \;\; \text{mod} \; 4$ and $2 \not \equiv 0 \;\; \text{mod} \; 4$ so there's no solution.

*Case 2.* If $a$ is odd then $a^{n+1}-(a+1)^n \equiv a \;\; \text{mod}\; 4$ as $a^n \equiv 1 \;\; \text{mod} \; 4.$ Thus, $a \equiv 2001 \equiv 1 \;\; \text{mod} \; 4 \; (\star \star).$  From $(\star), (\star \star)$ the only possibility is $a=13.$

Now, it boils down to solving $13^{n+1}-14^n=2001.$ If $n>2$ then $14^n \equiv 0 \;\; \text{mod} \; 8$ while $13^{n+1} \equiv 5^{2k+1} \equiv 25^k. 5 \equiv 5 \;\; \text{mod} \; 8$ and $5 \not \equiv 1 \;\; \text{mod} \; 8.$ Hence, $n=2$ and $(a,n)=(13,2)$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

I consider this as a fairly easy problem. Here is my approach-
Since RHS is divisible by $3$, the LHS is also divisible by $3$. But considering modulo $3$, $x$ must be congruent to $1$ mod $3$. Hence, considering mod $x$, i got $x$ $|$ $2002$.
Then considering mod ${x+1}$, i again got ${x+1}$$|$$2002$.
Now when i found the factors of $2002$, i got only $1$,$2$, and $13$,$14$ are the consecutive divisors of $2002$. But $x$$=$$1$ did not give solutions. So only possible case for $x$ was $13$. Now, i got that only $n$$=$$2$ satisfies. Hence there was only one pair $(13,2)$.

Comment: This does not require extensive case study